# How to define a "subclass of class" type?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript3.8

```
class SuperClass { ... }

class SubClass1 extends SuperClass { ... }
class SubClass2 extends SuperClass { ... }
class SubClass3 extends SuperClass { ... }

const foo: ??? = ...
```

For `foo` I'd like to give a type that means that `foo` is an instance of any class extending `SuperClass`. I know I could use union types and list all subclasses but there must be a better way. Somehow with `extends` or how to do it?

---

**Update:**

The reason I ask this is because I have this problem:

```
type SomeType = { foo: SuperClass };

public someMethod<T extends SuperClass>() {

  const bar: SomeType = ... ;

  const someSet: Set<T> = new Set();

  someSet.add(bar.foo);
```

> Argument of type 'SuperClass' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'T'. 'SuperClass' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T'
>   could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint
>   'SuperClass'.

Hmm.. maybe I should just change `Set<T>` to `Set<SuperClass>`.

Comment: Is there something unique about the subclasses that the parent class doesn't have? Why wouldn't you want the parent class to be passed?

Comment: Yes, there were some methods that only the subclasses contained but I realized it was a design error so I merged these into the superclass and now that I've fixed the inheritance I can pass the parent.

Comment: Makes sense, this felt like it had to be a design error =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want to achieve? `SuperClass` should be fine for `???`. If you want it to be union of EVERY subclasses of SuperClass: Well, it's not possible

Answer (score 1):

This is one variant:

```
interface Interface {}

class SuperClass implements Interface{  }

class SubClass1 extends SuperClass {  }

const foo: Interface = new SubClass1();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to have generic type, the closest answer I can come up is this:

```js
interface SuperClass {
    a: string;
}

type SomeType<T extends SuperClass> = { foo: T };

function someMethod<T extends SuperClass>(bar: SomeType<T>) {
    const someSet: Set<T> = new Set();

    someSet.add(bar.foo);
}
```